# Push into array inside reduced new Map()

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to push to an array on a `new Map()` reduce from an array of objects, but for some reason it pushes only two items per array.

```js
const data = [
  {
    keyword: 'engines',
    url: 'google.com',
  },
  {
    keyword: 'engines',
    url: 'duckduckgo.com',
  },
  {
    keyword: 'pc',
    url: 'mac.com',
  },
  {
    keyword: 'pc',
    url: 'linux.com',
  },
  {
    keyword: 'pc',
    url: 'windows.com',
  }
]

let urls = []

const mapper = data.reduce((acc, obj) => {
  urls.push(obj.url)
  if (!acc.has(obj.keyword)) {
    acc.set(obj.keyword, urls )
  } else {
    urls = []
  }
  return acc
}, new Map())


console.log(mapper)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Expected output

```
Map(2) {
  'engines' => [ 'google.com', 'duckduckgo.com'],
  'pc' => [ 'mac.com', 'linux.com', 'windows.com']
}
```

I dont even know why the snippet does not work on stackoverflow, it works fine on editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a compact implementation that will produce your output

```
data.reduce(
  (a, o) => a.set(o.keyword, [...a.get(o.keyword) || [], o.url]), 
  new Map()
)
```

Answer (score 1):

This gives you the correct output.

You need to use a new array for each keyword; otherwise you're sharing a single object and corrupting it as you go.

StackOverflow's REPL does not output `Map` content in the same way as browsers when using `console.log`, so I used a workaround to display the data.

```js
const data = [
  {
    keyword: 'engines',
    url: 'google.com',
  },
  {
    keyword: 'engines',
    url: 'duckduckgo.com',
  },
  {
    keyword: 'pc',
    url: 'mac.com',
  },
  {
    keyword: 'pc',
    url: 'linux.com',
  },
  {
    keyword: 'pc',
    url: 'windows.com',
  }
]

const mapper = data.reduce((acc, obj) => {
  if (!acc.has(obj.keyword)) {
    acc.set(obj.keyword, [] )
  }
  let urls = acc.get(obj.keyword)
  urls.push(obj.url);
  return acc;
}, new Map())

/**
Expected output per OP:
Map(2) {
  'engines' => [ 'google.com', 'duckduckgo.com'],
  'pc' => [ 'mac.com', 'linux.com', 'windows.com']
}
*/
console.log([...mapper.entries()])
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it with this but is does not feel right

```js
const data = [ { keyword: 'engines', url: 'google.com', }, { keyword: 'engines', url: 'duckduckgo.com', }, { keyword: 'pc', url: 'mac.com', }, { keyword: 'pc', url: 'linux.com', }, { keyword: 'pc', url: 'windows.com', } ]

let urls = []

const mapper = data.reduce((acc, obj) => {
 
  if (!acc.has(obj.keyword)) {
    urls = []
  } 

  urls.push(obj.url)
  
  acc.set(obj.keyword, urls )
  return acc
}, new Map())


console.log(mapper)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
const data = [
  {
    keyword: 'engines',
    url: 'google.com',
  },
  {
    keyword: 'engines',
    url: 'duckduckgo.com',
  },
  {
    keyword: 'pc',
    url: 'mac.com',
  },
  {
    keyword: 'pc',
    url: 'linux.com',
  },
  {
    keyword: 'pc',
    url: 'windows.com',
  }
]

const mapper = data.reduce((acc, obj) => {
  if (acc.has(obj.keyword)) {
      acc.set(obj.keyword,[...acc.get(obj.keyword), obj.url] )
  } else {
      acc.set(obj.keyword, [obj.url])
  }
  return acc
}, new Map())

/**
Expected output per OP:
Map(2) {
  'engines' => [ 'google.com', 'duckduckgo.com'],
  'pc' => [ 'mac.com', 'linux.com', 'windows.com']
}
*/

console.log(mapper)
```